# How to determine decay rate?

Tags: data-visualization, algorithms, computational-statistics

Three decay solid lines are plotted in the graph below. They are sqrt(1/n), sqrt(log(log(n))/n) and sqrt(log(n)/n) respectively.

I plot my dataset on the graph as the hdi dashed line. How to determine which decay line the hdi dashed line is closest to? In fact, for every decay line, I can multiply the hdi line by a constant to make it look very close to it. My question basically is: how to determine the decay rate for a given line?

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest you try log-log scaling on your plot; it should make it easier to see detail. Multiplication by a constant would be converted to a shift so you're just be looking for parallel curves.

Answer (score 1):

As advised in the comments (+1), since y-values are very small, you can't observe the asymptotical behaviors of the curves with this scale (at least clearly). Just add `plt.yscale('log')` to your plotting lines. It seems you're using Python matplotlib. Below is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize = (18,6))
n = np.arange(2,40000)

plt.plot(n, np.sqrt(1/n), color = 'orange')
plt.plot(n, np.sqrt(np.log(np.log(n))/n), color = 'green')
plt.plot(n, np.sqrt(np.log(n)/n), color = 'red')

plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

which has the following output:
[image]